# Why do I get System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: compiler-errors, .net-assembly, system.reflection, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I'm just trying to generate code that just generate a int constant. Here is the code:
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outputPath);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(outputPath);

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(name);

AssemblyBuilder assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave); //, Path.GetDirectoryName(outputPath));
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name, filename);

TypeBuilder programType = moduleBuilder.DefineType(name + ".Program");
MethodBuilder mainMethod = programType.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), System.Type.EmptyTypes);
assembly.SetEntryPoint(mainMethod);
ILGenerator generator = mainMethod.GetILGenerator();
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, (int)Value);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
programType.CreateType();
assembly.Save(filename);
```

And when i execute the .exe it gives that exception
Why?

Comment: Just like it says, your MSIL is not correct.  The stack is imbalanced, consider removing the Ldc_I4 instruction.

Comment: What do you mean with: the stack is imbalanced?
If I remove Ldc_I4 instruction then it would do nothing, that's not what I want. The behavior I want is like declaring a value that could be use or not. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbwdt101(v=vs.110).aspx), you define a method with a void return type.

But the IL you generates returns a int (the content of your stack before the ret instruction).

If you replace the defineMethod line by

```
MethodBuilder mainMethod = programType.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(int), System.Type.EmptyTypes);
```

You'll get things right.

You can usually find most of IL errors using [ILspy](http://ilspy.net/) to disassemble your executable (or library).

In your case, you'd see :

```
static void Main()
{
    12;
}
```

which is obviously wrong.